# PostgresSQL: Cannot get to console under different user name

Tags: postgresql

I normally get to the console in UBUNTU by typing:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

But I need to delete a database owned by a different user.

When I type:

```
sudo -u username psql
```

It tells me "database "username" does not exist.

But... I wasn't trying to connect to a database, I was trying to connect as a user.

Comment: I did make a lot of research effort, I went through the documentation linked below and somehow I still did not arrive at the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`psql` assumes you want to connect to the database named as the current user if you don't provide any login details.

But you can ovverride the defaults using parameters to `psql`, there is no need to use `sudo` in order to connect as a different username.

Simply run:

```
psql -U username -d databasename
```

where *username* is the user you want to use and *databasename* the database you want to connect to.

If you don't know which database you can connect to, use

```
psql -l
```

to show them all.

All this and a lot more is nicely documented in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

Comment: Thanks I finally got in as myself. Yet despite my database showing up under \l I can't seem to delete it using DROP DATABASE databasename;  It says it doesn't exist.